# macOS: Command not found: corepack when installing Yarn on Node v17.0.1

Tags: macos, yarnpkg, yarn-v2

I'm following the Yarn installation instructions on Yarn's website (https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install). Those instructions say that on Node version 16.10.0 and higher you can install Yarn by enabling corepack with the following command:

```
corepack enable
```

However, running that command returns:

```
zsh: command not found: corepack
```

I installed Node via Homebrew and `node -v` returns `v17.0.1`. I'm on an M1 Mac running Big Sur.

Comment: I would suggest use the LTS version of nod: `node:16.13.0`. Node 17 will never be LTS: https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue - installed node (16.13.1) with asdf. Was able to run corepack enable - but getting "zsh: command not found: yarn"

Comment: Corepack will not work in Node.js snap. https://github.com/nodejs/snap/issues/26

Answer (score 64):

Because I had installed node via nvm (and I had installed nvm using Homebrew), the corepack command wasn't available. The fix that worked for me was to install corepack via homebrew by running:

> brew install corepack

After installing corepack via homebrew, I was able to run the `corepack enable` command from the terminal and the `yarn` command became available as well.

Answer (score 43):

Was facing a similar issue with node installed using asdf. Also using zsh and zsh asdf plugin.

Node version: 16.13.1
Ran corepack enable - and got
`zsh: command not found: yarn`

What solved for me:
`asdf reshim nodejs`

Also try to run
`corepack prepare yarn@3.1.1 --activate`
before reshim

Comment: `asdf reshim nodejs` was what I needed, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I opened a PR to add this to the asdf nodejs plugin docs: https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-nodejs/pull/349

Comment: The `asdf reshim nodejs` was the trick!

Answer (score 10):

I solved it like this:

*From the https://github.com/nodejs/corepack docs*

```
npm uninstall -g yarn pnpm
npm install -g corepack
```

Use with 'sudo' if you're using OSX